# How to generate XSLT from BTM within pipeline?

Tags: xslt, azure-devops, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

We have some BizTalk-style maps - BTM files. In order to generate XSLT from a BTM, we can simply do this in visual studio:

[image]

How do we perform this same functionality within the Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Comment: I donot think it can be done from azure devops pipeline. If you need the xslt file in your pipeline, you can firstly generate it from visual studio, and then push it to your repo. so that the xslt file will be available in your pipeline.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If you explain that maybe we can solve your actual problem.   The XSLT will be in the compiled DLL for the maps project (or whichever project it is in).  I know this as I've had to use a de-compiler tool to recover the source code for a map.

Comment: If we start with a BTM file and source control and we need that compiled to an XsLT how do we do that? I need the XsLT for the release.

Comment: How does a dll get created? I have not seen this.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf please respond

Comment: The DLL gets created when you build the solution

Comment: Is that your hypothesis or experience? What kind of dll is going to be generated from an azure resource group project?

Comment: That is from experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your BizTalk Application Build pipeline should get the source of the project and the BTM files and compile it and create the DLLs.   So unless you are doing some custom XSLT, you do **not** need to have the XSLT separately.

If you are doing custom XSLT you can do the steps you have outlined in your question to generate the initial XSLT, copy the resulting XSTL into your project folder and add it to the project, you then click on the map grid and change the `Custom XSLT Path` to point to the XSLT.  You can then customise the XSLT and check it in as normal.

**Note**: Making changes to the map grid after this point will have no impact on the map execution, so I usually make it obvious that custom XSLT is being used by removing all links from the map.

**Note2:** You are limited to using XSLT 1.0 for the custom XSLT unless you are using BizTalk 2020 where you have the option to use either the Saxon 9 HE for XSLT or any other XSLT Transform Engine. [XSLT Transform Engine (Grid Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/technical-reference/xslt-transform-engine-grid-property)

Comment: we have azure devops, we dont have biztalk application build pipeline

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Azure Devops will also compile and create DLLs as that is what gets deployed.  You still have not explained why you need the XSLT, so we can't really help you unless you tell us what you are trying to achieve, rather than a step you think you need

Comment: sorry about that i just totally realized that my question makes no sense at all